# How += works with sets and lists

Tags: python, list, set, python-3.4

I get a wired situation with the concatenation of lists and sets.
For exemple I have a list and set

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
s = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

When I run code like:

```
l + s
```

I have an error (it's anticipated)

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "set") to list

But when I use `+=` I get result

```
l += s  # [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I know that there is a difference. That in the first situation I call method `operator.add(l, s)` and in the second it's `l.__iadd__(s)`. 
But Can someone explain me why there is a two different results? Why `__iadd__` change the type but `add()` raise an exception?

**UPDATE**

@Jon Clements was right about `list.extend`. And from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

> **list.extend(L)**
>
> Extend the list by appending all the items in the given list. Equivalent to a[len(a):] = L.

And in the end `l[len(s):] = s` works like a charm

Comment: `l + s` = half list half set. Which doesn't work. `l += s` = a list added a set of values to it. Which will work

Comment: `list`s `+=` effectively calls `list.extend` which takes any iterable as `+=` is supposed to be an *inplace* operation and in this case that can be achieved by calling `.extend` rather than doing `var = var + var2` (which fails if the variables aren't compatible types) (effectively `list.__iadd__ == list.extend`)

Comment: Not sure, but I think it's because with `l + s` it's not clear what type the result should be and thus Python is like "dude what are you doing", whereas with `l += s` it's clear what you want (modify the list) so Python does it.

Comment: @StefanPochmann It's not right because when you try to call "some string" += 12, it will give you an exception. But it's clear that you would like to have a string variable.

Comment: @OleksandrDashkov In that case there's a different issue, namely that Python doesn't know how to convert the int to a string in order to append it to the string. There are at least two standard ways to convert a number to a string: `str(12)` and `chr(12)`.

Comment: @Oleksandr as Stefan says there's an implicit conversion required there that Python isn't willing to make. What if it was "1" += 12... do I want "112" or 13? And should 12 + "3" be 15 or "123"? etc...

Comment: @JonClements Sure, but the same way it's not clear about lists and sets. when I run [1, 2, 3] += {3, 4, 5}, do I want [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, ] or {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. So I suppose that first value should declare the first variable type in this case. But it's not important as this case doesn't work with string. integer etc..